# How to login the page which is responded by the first request?

Tags: jmeter

I set up a http request in jmeter, and it responded with a login page.
How can I login that page?
p.s. I cannot access the login page directly.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf and record your browser traffic. It will record whatever actions performed by you in the browser. If you want to simulate Login, perform Login operation in browser after setting up as per in the link. It will record all HTTP requests sent by browser, and shown as HTTP samplers. I would suggest you to first go through basics of Jmeter and Browser. Your question is not constructive. improve it by asking specific problem that you encountered.

Comment: Jmeter simulates HTTP requests (using Java libraries, HTTPClient). You can either add HTTP samplers manually (takes lot of efforts) or use Test Script recorder to capture the HTTP requests. I would suggest you to record the Login operation to make faster simulations. Once Login scenario is recorded, replay it, if any issues you come across, edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This does help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be accessing login page directly. You test scenario should simulate real life user as close as possible, so your test plan needs to look as follows:

1. **HTTP GET request to Login Page** - mimic opening of the login page in the browser

   - Perform correlation if required
2. **HTTP POST request to Login Page** - login itself

References:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#building)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)
- [How To Use JMeter For Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication)